# Java: How to copy from network using credentials to local folder

Tags: java, fileinputstream, file-copying, jcifs

It seems that Java cannot use windows credentials.
I need to copy files from server that requires credentials to local folder.

I used "JCIFS" plugin to copy from server using SMB protocol.
But in this case I can only copy to local machine using smb too, so some folder should be shared at local PC. Such behaviour is inacceptable for my application cause it will be run at different PCs. 
Map network path as a drive and copy files by "FileInputStream" is inappropriate decision too.

How such problem can be resolved? Maybe file can be read to buffer and then from there to local folder? Files are small enough for that - 30-50Mb.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just had to use streams:

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(credentials);
SmbFile remoteFile = new SmbFile (sourceFile, auth);
InputStream inputStreamFromLan = remoteFile.getInputStream();
OutputStream outputStreamToLocal = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

              int bufferSize = 5096;

              byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
              int noOfBytes = 0;
                     while( (noOfBytes = inputStreamFromLan.read(b)) != -1 )
              {
                  outputStreamToLocal.write(b, 0, noOfBytes);
              }
              outputStreamToLocal.close();
              inputStreamFromLan.close();
```